# Mysterious White Space at Top of Page

Tags: css, google-maps, html, whitespace

I'm having trouble with some whitespace above my table. I have a table that holds two buttons and then right below it is a Google map. I would like to float the table over top of the map instead of having them listed, if you will. I get about ten pixels of white space and I am having so much trouble figuring out why. Any ideas? Here is the first part of my HTML:

```
   <body onload="initMap()">
<div>
    <table width="100%"  >
        <tr>
            <th height="45" align="right" bgcolor="#CED0D0"  scope="col">
                <a href = http://search.html class="classname">Search</a> 
                <a href = http://loggedout.html class="classname">Log Out</a>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </table>        
</div>   
<div id="map_canvas" style="float:left; width:100%; height:100%"></div>
```

Map CSS

```
html { height: 100% }
body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#map_canvas { height: 100% }

table.alerts {
    border-width: 8px;
    border-spacing: 2px;
    border-style: outset;
    border-color:#FFF;
    border-collapse: separate;
    background-color:#FFF;
    bottom:0;
    position:absolute;
    font-family:Lucida Grande, Tahoma, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    border-top-left-radius: 8px;
    border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
    float:left;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

table.alerts th {
    border-width: 8px;
    padding: 0px;
    border-style: none;
    border-color:#999;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    font-family:Arial-Black,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    font-size:130%;
}

table.alerts td {
    border-width: 0px;
    padding: 3px;
    border-style: none;
    border-color:#039;
    background-color: rgb(247, 247, 242);
    font-family:"Arial", Gadget, sans-serif;        
    font-weight:bold;
}

.black_overlay {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    z-index:1001;
    -moz-opacity: 0.8;
    opacity:.60;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}

.white_content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 13%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60%;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    z-index:1002;
    overflow: auto;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;           
}

#bar {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;  
    right: 0px;

}

#body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}


.greyBox{
    padding:7px;
    background-color:#c6c6c6;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    margin-left:4px;
    width:200px;
    height:26px;
    font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    text-align : center;
    font-size:130%;

}


.bottom{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; 
}

p.hide { 
    display: none; 
}
```

Button CSS:

```
.classname {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ededed), color-stop(1, #dfdfdf) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ededed 5%, #dfdfdf 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ededed', endColorstr='#dfdfdf');
    background-color:#ededed;
    -moz-border-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px;
    border-radius:6px;
    border:1px solid #dcdcdc;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#777777;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:6px 24px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #ffffff;
}.classname:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #dfdfdf), color-stop(1, #ededed) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #dfdfdf 5%, #ededed 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#dfdfdf', endColorstr='#ededed');
    background-color:#dfdfdf;
}.classname:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saved your code and loaded it in chrome and saw the whitespace at the top.  Looks to be from the `tr`, because you have the table set to border-collapse: separate and border-width : 8px and border-spacing set to 2px.  spacing + width = 10px.

So not seeing why you did this (or why you're using a table at all, honestly), I would add the following:

```
table {
    border-width: 0px;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Comment: I deleted all that jargon from the CSS. That was from some previous testing that I should have known to take out. I added what you suggested but it didn't seem to work. Am I missing something?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it figured out. It was some conflicting code from another CSS file. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Something I learned recently: inline-block elements have space between them from the white space in the actual html tree.  But that's probably not the source here.  Did you clean up the code in the question?  If so, I'll retest.  But I'd suggest not using a table, as it adds no apparent value in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your `<table width="100%">` tag with this one -

```
<table width="100%"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
```

Comment: As per your code given i create a mockup in my system and by applying the above code white space removed, so how can i come to know that your other css is conflicting, can you please explain that.