# Banner and top of page has blank space in between

Tags: html, css, margin, styling

there's this space between the transparent banner and top of the page. all the margin and padding options have been set to 0. i don't know what i'm doing wrong, any ideas?

image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kS1ZX.jpg

Body:

```
<video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
  <source src="sparkle.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>



        <div class="hero-image" >
            <h1 align="center" style="color:white; font-size:50px; font-family:Sofia;">Sparkle</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="ok">
            <H1 style="padding:0; margin:0; overflow:hidden;" align="center"> </h1>
        </div >
    <p style="position:relative;"> okok <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>  <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> okoks </p>
```

css:

```
body, html {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px ;
  padding:0px 0px 0px 0px ;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;


  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
}

#myVideo {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  z-index:-10
}



.hero-image {
  overflow:scroll
  margin:0;
  top:0;
  width: 100vw;
  position: sticky;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

Comment: it could be because of H1 margin-top. Try adding .hero-image h1{margin-top:0;}

Comment: Ah, that seems to have fixed it thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strange Blank Space at Top of Page – HTML, CSS, and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132747/strange-blank-space-at-top-of-page-html-css-and-php)

Answer (score 0):

Missing a comma after "overflow:scroll" which affects the next line of CSS

```
.hero-image {
  overflow:scroll; // semi-colon added
  margin:0;
  top:0;
  width: 100vw;
  position: sticky;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```